# sed replacing character in a file

Tags: command-line, text-processing, sed

I need to replace a single character in a`/etc/request-key.conf`

The file format is;

```
###############################################################################
#
# Copyright (C) 2005 Red Hat, Inc. All Rights Reserved.
# Written by David Howells (dhowells@redhat.com)
#
# This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or
# modify it under the terms of the GNU General Public License
# as published by the Free Software Foundation; either version
# 2 of the License, or (at your option) any later version.
#
###############################################################################


###############################################################################
#
# We can run programs or scripts
# - Macro substitutions in arguments:
#   %%...   %...
#   %o  operation name
#   %k  ID of key being operated upon
#   %t  type of key being operated upon
#   %d  description of key being operated upon
#   %c  callout info
#   %u  UID of requestor
#   %g  GID of requestor
#   %T  thread keyring of requestor (may be 0)
#   %P  process keyring of requestor (may be 0)
#   %S  session keyring of requestor (may be the user's default session)
#
################################################################################

#OP TYPE    DESCRIPTION CALLOUT INFO    PROGRAM ARG1 ARG2 ARG3 ...
#====== ======= =============== =============== ===============================
create  dns_resolver *      *               /sbin/key.dns_resolver %k
create  user    debug:*     negate      /bin/keyctl negate %k 30 %S
create  user    debug:*         rejected        /bin/keyctl reject %k 30 %c %S
create  user    debug:*         expired         /bin/keyctl reject %k 30 %c %S
create  user    debug:*         revoked         /bin/keyctl reject %k 30 %c %S
create  user    debug:loop:*    *       |/bin/cat
create  user    debug:*     *       /usr/share/keyutils/request-key-debug.sh %k %d %c %S
create  cifs.spnego *   *       /usr/sbin/cifs.upcall -c %k
create  dns_resolver    *   *       /usr/sbin/cifs.upcall %k
negate  *   *       *       /bin/keyctl negate %k 30 %S
```

So I need the 3rd last line to go from;

`create cifs.spnego * * /usr/sbin/cifs.upcall -c %k`

to;

`create cifs.spnego * * /usr/sbin/cifs.upcall -t %k`

I have tried;

`sed -i 's/^\(create  cifs.spnego *cifs.upcall\) \(%k\)/\1 -t \2/' /etc/request-key.conf`

Bu treally I just need to replace the `-c` with a `-t`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The golden rule in regular expressions is: less is more. Always try and find the *simplest* expression that is sufficient to target your search string. So instead of trying to match the entire line, look for a small, but unique, string:

```
$ grep -- -c file
create  cifs.spnego *   *       /usr/sbin/cifs.upcall -c %k
```

I saved your file as `file` and, as you can see, there is only one case of `-c` in the file. So all you need is (note the `-i.bak`, that will create a backup file):

```
sed -i.bak 's/-c/-t/' /etc/request-key.conf
```

If you want to be more prudent and make sure you match only your target line without searching first, just change the `-c` on any lines starting with `create cifs.spnego`. Note the use of `-E` for extended regular expressions and using `\s+` (1 or more whitespace) instead of trying to write multiple spaces:

```
sed -Ei.bak 's/^(create\s+cifs\.spnego.*cifs.upcall\s+)-c/\1 -t/' /etc/request-key.conf
```

Since you don't need to make any changes after the `-c`, there is no reason to try and match it: *less is more*.

---

The reason your attempt failed is because `*` is a multiplier in regular expressions, it means "0 or more". So when you have `cifs.spnego *cifs.upcall`, that looks for `cifs.spnego`, then *0 or more spaces*, followed by `cifs.upcall`. Your line, however, was:

```
create  cifs.spnego *   *       /usr/sbin/cifs.upcall  -t %k
```

To match that, you need to match `cifs.spnego`, then a space, then a `*`, then more spaces, and another `*`, then `/usr/sbin/` and only then do you have `cifs.upcall`. To match all of those, you would need (you need `\*` to match the character `*`):

```
/^create  cifs.spnego \*   \*       cifs.upcall/
```

Or, since less is more, simply:

```
/^create  cifs.spnego .*cifs.upcall/
```

The `.*` means "anything".

Comment: I think you want `s/-c/-t` not `s/-c/-k/` if I read the project scope correctly. Still +1 for "less is more".

Comment: I often favor separating the context pattern from the replacement pattern in situations like this - for example `sed '/cifs.spnego/ s/-c/-t/'`

Comment: @steeldriver yes, that makes a lot of sense.